# Add class to first letter of html text, remove leading white space and remain all html tag

Tags: jquery

I was research around stackoverflow and try my best to solve , but still facing some problem there..

Basically, I want to add `span` tag with `.first-letter` class name to the first letter of html text and remain all other html tag.

Below is the code that i try to do:

```js
// remove all leading white space in text
var contentText = $('.content-text').text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
 
// convert into html
$('.content-text').html(contentText);

// add class '.first-letter' into html but I missing all html tag because of text()
$('.content-text').html(function (index, html) {return '<span class="first-letter ">' + html.slice(0, 1) + '</span>' + html.slice(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12 content-text">
    <p>
     Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ameth Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolorsssss Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolo..
     </p>
               
     <p>
     Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ameth Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolorsssss Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolo..
      </p>
</div>
```

**the output of this code:**

`<span class="first-letter ">L</span>orem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ameth Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolorsssss Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolo..Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ameth Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolorsssss Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolo..`

**What I want to output:**

`<p><span class="first-letter ">L</span>orem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ameth Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolorsssss Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolo..</p><p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ameth Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolorsssss Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolo..</p>`

Comment: There is also a [:first-letter](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp) selector, so you don't have to put a span around the first letter yourself if you wanted to use it for CSS styling.

Comment: Is the only change that you want to wrap the output in a `<p></p>`? If so, just add it to the return value from `html()`...?

Comment: @Rick for some reason, `span class="first-letter"` is needed.

Comment: Also, Javascript strings have a [.trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) method, which removes removes whitespace from both sides of a string. It's nicer than using regex to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.content-text p:first-of-type`, you can easily target the first paragraph and replace the first letter.

See the example below. I've retained the `first-letter` class as you requested.

```js
$('.content-text p:first-of-type').html(function (index, html) {
  // trim the text
  text = html.trim();
  
  // replace the first letter and return the html
  return '<span class="first-letter">' + text.slice(0, 1) + '</span>' + text.slice(1);
});
```

```css
.first-letter {
  font-size:28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12 content-text">
    <p>
     Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ameth Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolorsssss Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolo..
     </p>
               
     <p>
     Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ameth Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolorsssss Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit AmethLorem Ipsum Dolo..
      </p>
</div>
```